# Adding array together with nil as a possibility

Tags: ruby, arrays, rspec, sum, each

I am creating a method that will take an array of numbers and add them together. I don't want to use `inject` because I haven't learned it yet. I prefer to start with the basics. I want to use either `each` or `while`.

I've been re-writing this code and testing it against `rspec`, and I keep running into a problem because the first test consists of the array being empty with `nil`. I tried doing an `if else` statement to set `nil` to `0` if the array is `empty?`, but that didn't seem to work. Here is what I've got right now.

```
def sum(x)
  total = 0 
  sum.each { |x| total += x}
  total
end
```

The `rspec` is testing an empty array `[]` as well as others that have multiple integers. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty with `nil`"?

Comment: Sorry... I guess it was a bit redundant, but I meant that one of the tests run is when the array is empty... and that returns nil instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not enumerating the array passed in to the method, you're enumerating the variable `sum`. You want `x.each { |x| total += x}`, although using `x` within the `{}` is a little odd in this case because you've used the name for your method parameter.

Comment: Peter!! Many thanks... I thought I had tried the x.each, but I think you are right.. it was strange that I used the x within {} so I decided to change it to num and it not only read clearer, but solved my issue!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`compact!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) to remove the `nil`s from your array.

```
def sum(x)
  total = 0
  x.compact! #lose the nils
  x.each { |i| total += i}
  total
end
```

Edit:
If the `x` being passed to your `sum()` method is `nil`, you can check for that with [`nil?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NilClass.html).

The do something like

```
if x.nil?
  0 #assuming you want to return 0
else
  #rest of your function
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return `nil` if the array passed in is empty?

You are getting confused with your identifiers. You are trying to iterate over `sum`, which is the name of the method, and you are using `x` as both the method parameter and the iteration block parameter.

I suggest you use something more descriptive, like `arr` for the method parameter and `v` for the block parameter (holding the value of each **v**alue from the array).

Finally, you need to initialise the total to `nil` so that the correct value is returned if the array is empty. Unfortunately you can't do arithmetic on `nil`, so in the code below I have added a line to set `total` to zero if it isn't already set.

This will do what you ask.

```
def sum(arr)
  total = nil
  arr.each do |v|
    total = 0 unless total
    total += v
  end
  total
end

p sum [1,2,3]
p sum []
```

**output**

```
6
nil
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a new instance method for the Array class:

```
class Array
  def sum
    total = 0.0
    self.each {|x| total += x if ['Fixnum', 'Float'].include?(x.class.name)}
    total%1==0 ? total.to_i : total
  end
end
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
puts [].sum                     # => 0
puts [1, 2, 3].sum              # => 6
puts [2, nil, "text", 4.5].sum  # => 6.5
```